# How to create symbol polynomial from given array with sympy?

Tags: python, sympy, polynomials

I am trying to calculate some polynomials given an input numerator and denominator polynomials as coefficient arrays.

How can I create my polynomials from these arrays?

E.g:

**Inputs:**

```
den= [2,3,4]
num= [1,3]
```

**Output:**
`(s+3)/(s^2+3*s+4)`

I need to use symbols because I will further need to divide the results by other polynomials and perform further polynomial computations.

P.S Is `sympy` suitable for this? I would usually solve things like this in `matlab` but I want to expand my knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is `(s+3)/(2*s^2+3*s+4)`, there is a typo in your original expression. And in Python, `^` is not power, power is `**`.

You just need a ordinary Python list comprehension:

```
from sympy import poly
from sympy.abc import s

den_ = sum(co*s**i for i, co in enumerate(reversed(den)))
num_ = sum(co*s**i for i, co in enumerate(reversed(num)))
res = num_/den_
```

Comment: Thank you very much.Indeed there was a typo.I didn't know how to put together the values as a polynomial but sum did it.

Answer (score 4):

You can do the following:

```
den = [2, 3, 4]
num = [1, 3]
x = symbols('x')
Poly(num, x)/Poly(den, x)
```

This creates Poly objects for the numerator and denominator (not just expressions). The coefficients are listed from the highest power of x.

Note that the result of division is an ordinary expression, since there is no RationalFunction type in SymPy. If you want to apply the tools from the `polys` module to the numerator and denominator, keep them separate as  a tuple.

Comment: Is there any roots/ get order method for this object?

Comment: For the Poly objects? [Tons of methods](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/polys/reference.html). Try `roots(Poly(den, x))` and `degree(Poly(den, x))`.

Comment: It seems i can't import name "polytools" and use the methods.

Comment: `from sympy import roots, degree` works for me. They don't have to be imported from polytools specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Use the classmethod `Poly.from_list`. The terms of the list are the coefficients in descending order of a polynomial of degree equal to `len(list)-1`

```
from sympy import Symbol, Poly

# coefs
num= [1,3]
den= [2,3,4]

# symbol
s = Symbol('s')

# polynomial
n = Poly.from_list(num, x)
d = Poly.from_list(den, x)

# expression
e = n/d
```